# How to install pystring on mac

Tags: python, macos, installation, homebrew

I've got a noob question. Anyone knows how I can install pystring on mac? I need its library and header. I tried installing it via brew but does not seem to be available there.

http://code.google.com/p/pystring/

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you referring to `PyStringObject`, the `PythonObject` that represents to a python string object? Or the `PyString` class from the `jython` package?

Comment: This is what I'm referring to [link](http://code.google.com/p/pystring/)

Comment: Have you tried downloading the source from GitHub and building it yourself? It seems like the most straight forward solution.

https://github.com/imageworks/pystring

Comment: I'm trying "make" it myself but it gives me this error: error: libtool: unknown option character `-' in: --mode=compile . Any idea why it's not getting compiled?